# a hibernate LazyInitializationException which is very trick

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-initialization

I have two piece of code segments, they are almost exactly the same, except their locations are different, one locates in RestLoginDLCtrl(a controller) the other locates in CouponManagerController(a controller).But one code segment is right, the other one throws org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException.

I know how to solve my problem. confused me the most is why one is OK the other is wrong, but they are almost the same code. why? Any help would be appreciate.

ConversionCode is a value object which has a set named codeRewards and managerService is a service class.

**note:**

Finally, I found some interesting phenomena. when I use ajax way to post the http request, two methods both well:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/CouponInfo/useConversionCode.do",
    data: {
        code: key
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

But when I use form way, two methods both did not work:Does hibernate lazy initialize mechnism has relationship with http request way?

```
<form action=""></form>
```

The CouponManagerController controller class:

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "${adminPath}/CouponInfo")
    public class CouponManagerController extends RestBaseCtrl {
        @Autowired
        CouponManagerService managerService;
        @ResponseBody
        public void useConversionCode(String code, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            response.setContentType("text/json;charset=utf-8");
            try {
                LoginCustInfo info = (LoginCustInfo) request.getSession().getAttribute(SystemProperties.DUOLIJR_LOGIN_USER);
                ConversionCode conversionCode = managerService.queryConversionCodeByCode(code);
                if (conversionCode != null) {
                    managerService.useConversionCode(conversionCode, info.getCustId());
                    response.getWriter().print("[{\"success\":\"true\",\"message\":\"兑换成功\"}]");
                } else {
                    response.getWriter().print("[{\"success\":\"false\",\"message\":\"无效兑换码\"}]");

                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    response.getWriter().print("[{\"success\":\"false\",\"message\":\"兑换失败！请稍后重试！\"}]");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    response.getWriter().print("[{\"success\":\"false\",\"message\":\"兑换失败！请稍后重试！\"}]");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The RestLoginDLCtrl controller class:

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "${adminPath}/yqxqrest/loginDLCtrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public class RestLoginDLCtrl extends RestBaseCtrl {
        @Autowired
        CouponManagerService managerService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "useConversionCode")
        @ResponseBody
        public void useConversionCode(String code, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

            response.setContentType("text/json;charset=utf-8");
            try {
                LoginCustInfo info = (LoginCustInfo) request.getSession().getAttribute(SystemProperties.DUOLIJR_LOGIN_USER);
                ConversionCode conversionCode = managerService.queryConversionCodeByCode(code);
                if (conversionCode != null) {
                    managerService.useConversionCode(conversionCode, info.getCustId());
                    response.getWriter().print("[{\"success\":\"true\",\"message\":\"兑换成功\"}]");
                } else {
                    response.getWriter().print("[{\"success\":\"false\",\"message\":\"无效兑换码\"}]");

                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    response.getWriter().print("[{\"success\":\"false\",\"message\":\"兑换失败！请稍后重试！\"}]");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    response.getWriter().print("[{\"success\":\"false\",\"message\":\"兑换失败！请稍后重试！\"}]");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The CouponManagerServiceImpl service class:

```
    @Service("ActivitiesCouponsService")
    public class CouponManagerServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl implements CouponManagerService {

        @Autowired
        JdbcDao jdbcDao;
        @Autowired
        ActivitiesCouponsService couponsService;
        @Override
        public ConversionCode queryConversionCodeByCode(String code){
            ConversionCode conversionCode=null;
            String hql = " from ConversionCode where DELETE_FLAG=0 and state=0 and code='"+code+"'";
            List<ConversionCode> codes = jdbcDao.find(hql);
            if (codes.size()>0) {
                conversionCode=codes.get(0);
            }

            return conversionCode;
        }

        /**
         * 使用兑换码
         * @param conversionCode
         * @param custId
         * @throws ParseException
         */
        @Override
        public void useConversionCode(ConversionCode conversionCode,Integer custId) throws ParseException {

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date now = new Date();
            Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            endTime.setTime(sdf.parse(sdf.format(now)));

            Set<ConversionCodeReward> codeRewards=conversionCode.getCodeRewards();

            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
            String a="";
            for(ConversionCodeReward codeReward:codeRewards) {
                CustActivitiesInfo activitiesInfo = new CustActivitiesInfo();
                activitiesInfo.setCustId(custId);
                activitiesInfo.setCouponsType(codeReward.getCouponsType());
                String couponsName=couponsService.findUcTypeDictionaryBycode("COUPONS_TYPE", codeReward.getCouponsType() + "").getItemName();
                activitiesInfo.setCouponsName(couponsName);
                activitiesInfo.setActivitiesAmount(codeReward.getActivitiesAmount());

                endTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Integer.valueOf(codeReward.getValidPeriod()));
                endTime.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1);
                activitiesInfo.setStartDate(sdf.parse(sdf.format(now)));
                activitiesInfo.setEndDate(endTime.getTime());
                activitiesInfo.setTaskAction("兑换码");
                activitiesInfo.setUseMeetAmount(codeReward.getUseMeetAmount());
                activitiesInfo.setUsePlanType(codeReward.getUsePlanType());
                activitiesInfo.setUsePlanPeriod(codeReward.getUsePlanPeriod());
                activitiesInfo.setState(1);
                jdbcDao.saveObject(activitiesInfo);

                sb.append("1张"+codeReward.getCouponsName()+"、");

            }
            conversionCode.setState(1);
            jdbcDao.updateObject(conversionCode);


        }

    }
```

The ConversionCode value object class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "conversion_code")
    public class ConversionCode extends BaseEntity implements java.io.Serializable{

        private int id;
        private String code;
        private Date endDate;
        private int state;
        private String remark;
        private Set<ConversionCodeReward> codeRewards;

        public ConversionCode(int id,String code,Date endDate,int state,String remark){
            super();
            this.id=id;
            this.code=code;
            this.endDate=endDate;
            this.state=state;
            this.remark=remark;
        }
        public  ConversionCode(){

        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Column(name = "code")
        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        @Column(name = "end_date")
        public Date getEndDate() {
            return endDate;
        }

        public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
            this.endDate = endDate;
        }

        @Column(name = "state")
        public int getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setState(int state) {
            this.state = state;
        }


        @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="codes")
        public Set<ConversionCodeReward> getCodeRewards() {
            return codeRewards;
        }

        public void setCodeRewards(Set<ConversionCodeReward> codeRewards) {
            this.codeRewards = codeRewards;
        }

        @Column(name = "remark")
        public String getRemark() {
            return remark;
        }

        public void setRemark(String remark) {
            this.remark = remark;
        }
    }
```

The ConversionCodeReward value object class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "conversion_code_reward")
    public class ConversionCodeReward extends BaseEntity implements java.io.Serializable{

        private Integer id;
        private String couponsName;
        private int couponsType;
        private double activitiesAmount;
        private int validPeriod;
        private double useMeetAmount;
        private String usePlanType;
        private int usePlanPeriod;
        private Set<ConversionCode> codes;

        public ConversionCodeReward(Integer id,String couponsName,int couponsType,double activitiesAmount,
                                    int validPeriod,double useMeetAmount,String usePlanType,int usePlanPeriod){
            super();
            this.id=id;
            this.couponsName=couponsName;
            this.couponsType=couponsType;
            this.activitiesAmount=activitiesAmount;
            this.validPeriod=validPeriod;
            this.useMeetAmount=useMeetAmount;
            this.usePlanType=usePlanType;
            this.usePlanPeriod=usePlanPeriod;
        }

        public ConversionCodeReward(){

        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Column(name = "coupons_name")
        public String getCouponsName() {
            return couponsName;
        }

        public void setCouponsName(String couponsName) {
            this.couponsName = couponsName;
        }

        @Column(name = "coupons_type")
        public int getCouponsType() {
            return couponsType;
        }

        public void setCouponsType(int couponsType) {
            this.couponsType = couponsType;
        }

        @Column(name = "activities_amount")
        public double getActivitiesAmount() {
            return activitiesAmount;
        }

        public void setActivitiesAmount(double activitiesAmount) {
            this.activitiesAmount = activitiesAmount;
        }

        @Column(name = "valid_period")
        public int getValidPeriod() {
            return validPeriod;
        }

        public void setValidPeriod(int validPeriod) {
            this.validPeriod = validPeriod;
        }

        @Column(name = "use_meet_amount")
        public double getUseMeetAmount() {
            return useMeetAmount;
        }

        public void setUseMeetAmount(double useMeetAmount) {
            this.useMeetAmount = useMeetAmount;
        }

        @Column(name = "use_planType")
        public String getUsePlanType() {
            return usePlanType;
        }

        public void setUsePlanType(String usePlanType) {
            this.usePlanType = usePlanType;
        }

        @Column(name = "use_planPeriod")
        public int getUsePlanPeriod() {
            return usePlanPeriod;
        }

        public void setUsePlanPeriod(int usePlanPeriod) {
            this.usePlanPeriod = usePlanPeriod;
        }

        @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH},fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name = "code_and_reward",
                joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "reward_id") },
                inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "code_id") })
        @Where(clause="DELETE_FLAG=0")
        public Set<ConversionCode> getCodes() {
            return codes;
        }

        public void setCodes(Set<ConversionCode> codes) {
            this.codes = codes;
        }
    }
```

The stack trace of the exception:

```
    2015-12-16 15:38:34,059 ERROR (org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException:19) - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.yiqixiangqian.entity.ConversionCode.codeRewards, no session or session was closed
    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.yiqixiangqian.entity.ConversionCode.codeRewards, no session or session was closed
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:358)
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:350)
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:343)
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:163)
        at com.yqxqfront.coupon.service.impl.CouponManagerServiceImpl.useConversionCode(CouponManagerServiceImpl.java:152)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at com.yiqixiangqian.common.log.LogAspect.around(LogAspect.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor255.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.useConversionCode(Unknown Source)
        at com.yqxqfront.rest.controller.RestLoginDLCtrl.useConversionCode(RestLoginDLCtrl.java:665)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.yqxqfront.rest.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.yqxqfront.filter.ImageVerifyCodeFilter.doFilter(ImageVerifyCodeFilter.java:66)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1774)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Hibernate: select custmessag0_.UID as UID245_, custmessag0_.CREATE_DATE as CREATE2_245_, custmessag0_.CREATED_BY as CREATED3_245_, custmessag0_.DELETE_FLAG as DELETE4_245_, custmessag0_.LAST_UPDATE_DATE as LAST5_245_, custmessag0_.UPDATE_BY as UPDATE6_245_, custmessag0_.VERSION as VERSION245_, custmessag0_.CONTENT as CONTENT245_, custmessag0_.CUST_ID as CUST9_245_, custmessag0_.ISCHECK as ISCHECK245_, custmessag0_.PUB_DATE as PUB11_245_, custmessag0_.TITLE as TITLE245_, custmessag0_.TYPE as TYPE245_ from cust_message custmessag0_ where custmessag0_.CUST_ID=? and custmessag0_.ISCHECK=? and custmessag0_.DELETE_FLAG=0
    failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.yiqixiangqian.entity.ConversionCode.codeRewards, no session or session was closed
```

The useConversionCode() method which locates in CouponManagerController controller is OK:

[image]

The useConversionCode() method which locates in RestLoginDLCtrl controller is wrong and throws a LazyInitializationException exception:

[image]

Comment: We don't need images. We need code, as text, and the complete stack trace of the exception, as text.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your tip and I add the code and the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: What is `RestBaseCtrl`?

Comment: @GergelyBacso  which is a util class to find current login user`s infomation.Finally, I found some interesting phenomena. when I ajax way post the http request two methods both well, but when I use form way, two methods both did not work.

Comment: Finally, I found some interesting phenomena. when I use ajax way to post the http request, two methods both well.but when I use form way, two methods both did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how this issue occured.Suddenly, I found there is a OpenSessionInViewFilter in the web.xml file.

```
<filter>
<filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>   
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter 
    </filter-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In my form post request way, I did not add the .do request suffix, so the OpenSessionInViewFilter did not work, so the LazyInitializationException occured.

But the ajax post request way added the .do request suffix, so the OpenSessionInViewFilter worked and LazyInitializationException did not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found some interesting phenomena. when I use ajax way to post the http request, two methods both well:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/CouponInfo/useConversionCode.do",
        data: {
            code: key
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
```

but when I use form way, two methods both did not work:

```
<form action=""></form>
```

Does hibernate lazy initialize mechnism has relationship with http request way?